# SSL certificates

Tags: apt, updates, ssl

I noticed that the Ubuntu Software Updates  downloads updates on port 80 and not by secure socket layer.  Can I force the updates to certificate driven downloads for increased security by editing the `sources.list' file.  I could always try first but I thought I'd ask.

Also, I noticed that by default there are *un-trusted* certificates in the Chromium browser.  Should I have anything to worry about?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `https://url` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`, then APT will use HTTPS.

`apt`verifies the signature of packages. So you do not need to have a form of transportation like  `apt-transport-https` that provides data authentication. If an attacker modifies the files you're downloading, this will be noticed. Using a signature verification is better than using an HTTPS connection, because it will detect an attack on the server you're downloading from, not just an attack in transit.